# Remote Desktop Services and Oracle 9i

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, oracle, remote-desktop-services

I have an Oracle 9i forms application installed on clients. I am looking at moving this to RDS. Is this possible?

Comment: There is **nowhere near enough information** here for us to help you. We know nothing about your application - so I'm going to say that the answer is an unequivocal "Maybe." :-)

Answer (score 1):

Forms 9i is a web based architecture (with a thick java client in the browser). I've known Forms stuff to be run through Remote Desktop / VNC as a 'work from home / remote site' solution, but it doesn't particularly make sense to me as the main configuration.

The main point about an n-tier architecture is that it removes the need to deploy your application to multiple (dozens/hundreds) of clients for each bug-fix.

Comment: Ah, no ;) There are other main points. Like remoting the application for perforamnce, uptime of desktops (think client = fast replace, virtual desktop can be highly available). Security (isolate the other network, often used in financail areas).